# Android gradle build: how to set global variables

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How can I set a global variable that can be accessed from build.gradle and tasks?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To set a global variable

```
project.ext.set("variableName", value)
```

To access it from anywhere in the project:

```
project.variableName
```

For instance:

```
project.ext.set("newVersionName", versionString)
```

and then...

```
println project.newVersionName
```

For more information see: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html

**EDIT**:
As commented by Dmitry, In new versions you can use the following shorthand:

```
project.ext.variableName = value
```

Comment: you can also access variables from gradle.properties the same way

Comment: Even shorter way to define a variable is `project.ext.variableName = value` (without explicitly calling `project.ext.set`)

Comment: can you set values to it in tasks?

Comment: Why is it that .ext is needed when setting it and not when reading it ? Imagine this was the syntax in any other programming language - that would drive me crazy...

Comment: Why did you ask a question and immediately answered it some minutes later? For documentation issues? ^^

Comment: Can this be done in any .gradle file in a project and not just the root gradle file?

Answer (score 32):

The answer from Guy is excellent. I just want to add the practical code.

Example:

Put something like this in the **Project** *build.gradle*:

```
project.ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

And put something like this in the **Module** *build.gradle* to access it:

```
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel project.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel project.targetSdkVersion
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also do this. Let's say you want to add appcompat with the version `25.3.1`, you can add a variable `version_name` in your project level *build.gradle*.

```
buildscript{
     ext.version_name = '25.3.1'
}
```

Now you can add this to your application level build gradle and avoid any conflicts.

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$version_name"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$version_name"
compile "com.android.support:design:$version_name"
```

Comment: How to get this ext.version_name value from Java? I want to add it to logs.

Comment: @RytisGuntulis [This might be relevant](https://www.tanelikorri.com/tutorial/android/set-variables-in-build-gradle/)

Answer (score 3):

You cant create a Gradle file in the project's root directory and put all variables there, like this:

**lib-versions.gradle**

```
   ext {
        kt_core = '1.6.0'
        app_compat = '1.3.1'
        material = '1.4.0'
        constraintlayout = '2.1.1'
        nav_version = '2.3.5'
        junit = '4.13.2'
        junit_ext = '1.1.3'
        escpresso = '3.4.0'
    }
```

Then in the project **build.gradle** file on the bottom you should apply the Gradle file like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply from: 'lib-versions.gradle' //apply it like this
```

Then you are able to use the variables in any module-level build Gradle file (**app/build.gradle**) like this:

```
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$rootProject.ext.kt_core"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.ext.app_compat"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.ext.material"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.ext.constraintlayout"
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional, for **dynamic global variables** you can define **global functions** in the master `build.gradle` file:

First, define your function, for example for git branch:

```
def getGitBranch = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

In `allProjects` section set the variable:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    project.ext {
        gitBranch="\"${getGitBranch()}\""
    }
}
```

In your `build.gradle` files of your **sub projects** or **android modules**, get this variable like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion project.mCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.mMinSdkVersion.toInteger()
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "GitBranch", project.gitBranch
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can use it in your code like this:

```
public static String getGitBranch() {
    return BuildConfig.GitBranch;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**).

Root (top-level) build file:

```kotlin
val myVariable by extra("watermelon")
// Alternative notations:
// extra.set("myVariable", "watermelon")
// extra["myVariable"] = "watermelon"
```

Extra properties on a *project* object are visible from its subprojects. Note that `extra.` is equivalent to `project.extra.`; in other words [the `project` object is implicit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_build_script_primer.html#groovy:project_object).

A sub-project build file:

```kotlin
val myVariable: String by rootProject.extra
// Alternative notations:
// val myVariable: String by rootProject
// val myVariable: String = rootProject.extra["myVariable"] as String
// val myVariable: String = rootProject.extra.get("myVariable") as String
```

Note that when using [Kotlin delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) (`by` keyword) the name of the variables should be the same in both build files.

See [Gradle Docs: Extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties) for more information.