# Rename file in gradle with passed parameter

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm packaging up my build artefacts from a gradle build. It's an Android Studio project.

I have tasks that successfully create a zip file containing two jars. Let's say the zip file is called '`my.zip`'.

I have the following gradle task:

```
task renameArtifacts (type: Copy) {
    from ('build/')
    include 'my.zip'
    destinationDir file('build/')
    doLast {
        println "my-${versionString}.zip"
        rename('build/my.zip', "build/my-${versionString}.zip")
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it with `gradle -PversionString="123" :sdk:renameArtifacts`

I have a `println` in the `doLast` closure and can see the my string interpolation is working correctly as it outputs `my-123.zip`.

However, `'my.zip'` is not renamed to `'my-123.zip'`. It remains `'my.zip'` and in fact results in a file with a size of zero bytes and is no longer openable as a zip file.

I'm obviously going wrong somewhere, but where?

Full gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar')
}

task updateVersionNumber() << {
    ant.replace(file: 'src/main/java/com/my/Version.java', token: '{{VERSION}}', value: versionString)
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("build/javadoc")
    failOnError false
}

task createJavaDocJar(type: Jar) {
    from ('build/javadoc')
    destinationDir file('build')
    baseName = 'my_doc'
}
createJavaDocJar.dependsOn(javadoc)

task packageMyJarAndDependencies(type: Jar) {
    from (zipTree('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar')) {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/'
    }
    from (zipTree('libs/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar')) {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/'
    }
    from (zipTree('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar')) {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/'
    }
    from (zipTree('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.1.0.jar'))
    from (zipTree('build/intermediates/bundles/release/classes.jar'))
}

task createFinalJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/libs/')
    into('build')
    include('sdk.jar')
    rename('sdk.jar', 'my.jar')
}
createFinalJar.dependsOn(clean, build, packageMyJarAndDependencies)
packageMyJarAndDependencies.mustRunAfter build
build.mustRunAfter clean

task zipArtifacts(type: Zip) {
    from ('build/')
    from ('build/libs')
    include 'my_doc.jar'
    include 'my.jar'
    baseName = 'my_lib'
    destinationDir file('build')
}
zipArtifacts.dependsOn(createFinalJar, createJavaDocJar)

task renameArtifacts (type: Copy) {
    from ('build/')
    into('build')
    include 'my_lib.zip'
    doLast {
        println "my_lib-${versionString}.zip"
        rename "my_lib.zip", "my_lib-${versionString}.zip"
    }
}
renameArtifacts.dependsOn(zipArtifacts)
```

Comment: Try this:                                                                                                        task myJar(type: Jar)

artifacts {
    archives myJar
}                                                                                                                                                              It is important to note that the custom archives you are creating as part of your build are not automatically assigned to any configuration. You have to explicitly do this assignment.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm just trying to rename a file

Comment: Please Post your build.gradle file

Comment: Done - full gradle file added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename` is a method on `CopyProcessingSpec`, that configures the task to perform some renamings while operating. If you wrap it in `doLast`, the copying has already happened, and no rename will be performed. Furthermore, rename takes only file names, not relative or absolute file paths. This should work:

```
project.ext.versionString = versionString
task renameArtifacts (type: Copy) {
    from ('build/')
    include 'my.zip'
    destinationDir file('build/')
    rename 'my.zip', "my-${project.versionString}.zip"
}
```

Edit: $versionString is not accessible in tasks. Using extra project property is the suggested way how to pass these in tasks (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600621/android-gradle-build-how-to-set-global-variables)).

Comment: Ok, understood. But the reason I was trying the doLast way is because otherwise I get "Could not find property 'versionString' on task ':sdk:renameArtifacts'". I'm passing versionString on the command line like: gradle -PversionString="123" :sdk:renameArtifacts

Comment: So how can I access the passed in versionString parameter?

Comment: Thanks. To pass the parameter in I had to remove the `project.ext.versionString=versionString` line and add an `if (project.hasProperty("versionString"))` guard around the rename. It's now working.