# Gradle variable is not in scope for copy and rename task

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to use a variable (populated from a shared file) to add a version number when the war is created by spring boot's bootWar plugin. However, it seems like the variable is not in scope. I added a doFirst to the bootWar to show that the variable is indeed populated before the war is created. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222724/rename-file-in-gradle-with-passed-parameter) suggests using project, but that also does not work (second try below). Is it not possible to use a variable at this point of the build process?

```
task populateBuildVersion (dependsOn: ["buildVersionFromFile", "buildVersionPlaceholder"]){
  doLast {
        project.ext.buildVersion = buildVersion
    println "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    println "|   Build version: $buildVersion"
    println "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  }
}

bootWar {
  into('') {
    from "${project(':web').projectDir}/src/main/webapp"
        // PICK ONE, COMMENT THE OTHERS:
        rename "webpacked.js", buildVersion // fails at task runtime with "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: replacement"
        rename "webpacked.js", project.buildVersion // fails at initialization with "Could not get unknown property 'buildVersion' for root project 'myproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project."
        rename "webpacked.js", "${buildVersion}.js" // results in null.js
  }
    doFirst {
        println "in bootWar dofirst: ${buildVersion}" // OK
        println buildVersion // OK
        println project.buildVersion // OK
    }
}
tasks.bootWar.dependsOn(populateBuildVersion)
```

Output:

```
> Task :populateBuildVersion
------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Build version: xyz_7.8.2_2417
------------------------------------------------------------------

> Task :bootWar
in bootWar dofirst: xyz_7.8.2_2417
xyz_7.8.2_2417
xyz_7.8.2_2417

> Task :bootWar FAILED (for various reasons)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rename` method that takes a Closure or a `Transformer<String, String>` as argument. The closure (or the Transformer) will be called when the task is executed. In your version, the property is accessed when the task is configured, and thus the `populateBuildVersion` task has not been executed yet:

```
from("${project(':web').projectDir}/src/main/webapp") {
    rename {
        it == 'webpacked.js' ? "${buildVersion}.js" : null
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That configuration-time vs. runtime context in Gradle has bitten me again.